# How to know accessibility tools(talkback, voiceover) are on by javascript?

Tags: javascript, webview, accessibility, voiceover, talkback

I'm developing webview. I want to check user who is using accessibility tools like voiceover(iOS), talkback(android).
Can I check these accessibility tools are running by javascript??

Comment: There's no reliable way to do this and lots of good reasons - user privacy being prominent among them - not to do this even if it is partially possible. Just develop your site properly so it works for all users, whether they use a screenreader or not!

Comment: There's a good discussion of this topic [here](https://adrianroselli.com/2014/03/onscreenreaderdetection.html) (Weirdly the link is taking me to a 404 page but if I copy it and paste it directly into a new tab, it works...)

Comment: too late to edit, but now I'm on a laptop rather than a phone it seems [this](https://adrianroselli.com/2014/03/on-screen-reader-detection.html) is the correct link